# overloaded << insertion operator isn't working correctly

Tags: c++, linked-list, ostream

So I can't figure out why my insertion operator isn't working for my list class. I've looked at it for a while and I think the syntax is correct for overloading. Not sure on this one. Any hints as to why it's not working?? Here's the code:

EDIT:Changed some code around to what it currently is right now.

Sorry, the problem specifically now is that I cannot get it to print anything out, it simple prints and empty line.

here's the driver:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "polynomial.h"

using namespace std;

int main(){
Polynomial* poly = new Polynomial();    

poly->set_coefficient(3,2);

poly->set_coefficient(0,2);

poly->set_coefficient(3,1);

cout << "trying to print data" << endl;
cout << *poly << endl;    
return 0;   
}
```

Here's the header:

```
#ifndef _POLYNOMIAL_H_
#define _POLYNOMIAL_H_

#include <iostream>

class Polynomial {

public:

struct PolyNode {
    int coefficient, degree;
    struct PolyNode* next;      
    PolyNode(int c, int d, PolyNode* n): coefficient(c),degree(d),next(n){}
};

PolyNode* firstTerm;
Polynomial(): firstTerm(0) {} 

struct PolyNode* get_first(){
    return firstTerm;
}


//makes the term with degree d have a coefficient of c
void set_coefficient(int c, int d);     

~Polynomial();  

friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Polynomial& p);          
};

#endif
```

Here's the implementation:

```
#include "polynomial.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

using namespace std;

void Polynomial::set_coefficient(int c, int d){
PolyNode* start = firstTerm;
if(c != 0 && firstTerm == 0)    
    firstTerm = new PolyNode(c,d,NULL);
else{   
    cout << "Entered set_coefficient()" << endl;
    while(start->degree != d && start->next != NULL){
        cout << "Inside set_coefficient() while loop" << endl;          
        start = start->next;        
    }       
    if(c != 0 && start == 0)    
        start = new PolyNode(c,d,0);
    else if(c!= 0 && start != 0)
        start->coefficient = c;
    else if(c == 0){
        cout << "deleting a term" << endl;          
        delete start;
    }
}   
    cout << "Leaving set_coefficient()" << endl;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& o,const Polynomial& p){
Polynomial::PolyNode* start = p.firstTerm;  
for(unsigned int i = 0; start->next != 0; i++){
    o << "Term " << i << "'s coefficient is: " << start->coefficient << " degree is: " << start->degree << endl << flush;
    start = start->next;
}   
return o;
}
```

Comment: "It's not working" is not a valid problem description. Does it fail to compile? Does it crash at runtime? Does it run without crashing, but produces unexpected results? Try to add that kind information when you post questions. I also recommend reading [Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes It is when I use the insertion in the main method. It should print out the data for the 2 terms that made in the list but instead it prints out a memory address.

Comment: @Keoki Zee. I'll put one for you :)

Comment: @Ben Voigt Thanks. I took your advice and now it only prints out a blank link which makes me wonder whether or not I am actually storing anything when I use set_coefficient.

Comment: @infinite_loop: I would have `operator<<` print something unconditionally (outside the for loop), and then grab my debugger, set a breakpoint in `set_coefficient` and in `operator<<`, and see what's going on.

Comment: @infinite_loop: I don't see anywhere that `firstTerm` gets changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`poly` is a pointer, to use your custom `operator <<` you need to say

```
cout << *poly; // output the object pointed-to, not the pointer itself
```

You haven't overloaded what it means to insert a `Polynomial*`.  Nor should you try.

Besides that, you probably should accept the object by `const` reference, there's no reason for a stream output operator to go changing the object.